# I can't change my password

Tags: raspbian

I cannot change the password on my raspberry pi. I've tried everything, and it always leads me to a message- "Enter new UNIX password:" The problem is that I lose the ability to type and therefore can't change the password. The only way I can get out of the message(other than to completely close it) is to press enter and get the message to retype the password, then a message that the passwords don't match, then a message that the password remained unchanged.

Comment: your post is titled `I can't change my password`, but that does not appear to be the problem ... `I lose the ability to type` ... why is your question not about that?

Comment: the typing isn't the problem, as far as I know. It only happens when I try to change my password, not letting me change my password. Sorry, next time I'll be more clear.

Comment: You didn't say whether you are in a graphical environment or at the command line. If you're at the command line, do know that the passwords you enter are not echoed. For instance, if you type a new password, and then retype it, instaead of just pressing enter, it will change the password. Just be sure to type the new password VERY carefully!

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your issue. According your subject you want to change the password. Which command do you use? Frankly I think you want to login and get a message to change your pwd. Do you use ssh to login? Do you use a UI? You have to describe in much more detail your issue. Otherwise nobody will be able to give you any help.

Comment: Please remember that the characters you enter as a password are not echoed (you will not see them as you type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (if I'm understanding your question) what you are seeing is the intended behaviour for the `passwd` command -- although I can't find it documented on the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html) for the command.

When you use the command and you enter your new password there's no feedback on the terminal to let you know that you've typed anything. In other words the command is expecting you to enter your new password "blind". Logging in on the terminal or over SSH has the same behaviour: you blindly type in the password at the prompt.

I've been unable to find some configuration to change this to get something on the screen (like '#' or '*' maybe). My guess would be that this is a security measure of some sort, maybe to stop people from guessing the length of your password or something from the old teletype days?