# Getting Ip address 169.254.xx.xx

Tags: ssh, putty

My question is not the same as other question like this. In the following i will describe why. 
When I tried to connect raspberry (3 b+) to laptop, via Puttty (laptop's OS is Windows 10), I could not even access by using `raspberrypi.local` or `raspberrypi.mshome.net`. I tried variety ip addresses and finally get access with ip address 192.168.xx.xx. But getting following error:
`login as: pi
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Password:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Password:`
also i read similar answers, there recommended to get ip addresss by changing network adapter to DHCP instead of static. But, when I changed it, internet connection was disabled. 
My question is :

- WHat means above written error?
- Does it means that it is own ip address of raspberry,
  even Putty has session error? ( To be honest, I thought that i found own ip address of raspberry, because Putty opens session's window. Whereas, another ip addresses was failt)
- If it is real ip address of raspberry, could i assign it as static ip address by the command `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and remotely control with ssh?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do I understand it right that you ask, why putty on MS Window$ give you error messages?  But this is a site belonging to Raspberry Pi. What's the problem with Raspberry Pi? Do you have enabled ssh on the RasPi?

Comment: That looks like a normal output from PuTTY v0.71 --- have you tried entering the password at the `Password:` prompt? Note that when you type the password nothing is shown on the screen (i.e you enter passwords "blind"). See also my answer to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100923/93934).

Comment: @RogerJones, Thank you so much for reply and sorry for answering too late! Yes, I knew about it from senpai's like you, but the problem was concerned with network of company. Unfortunately, I put it to do later. Thank you Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is incoherent, and you have not clearly explained what you have done.

It appears that you are directly connecting your Pi to your laptop.

If correctly configured that will work, and you should be able to access the Pi by `ssh`, either with a static IP address or [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address), although the methods may be Windows specific.

**NOTE** `ssh` needs to be enabled on the Pi for this to succeed.

You can enable Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on the laptop and access the internet from the Pi.

What you **CANNOT** do is have ICS and `ssh` access - you can have one or the other. (Variants of this question have been asked dozens of times.)

To save yourself a lot of grief, I suggest you connect the PI to your router (either by Ethernet or WiFi) the way it is designed to be used.

It is possible to `ssh` over a direct connection while the Pi has a WiFi connection to a router for internet access, but you need to explicitly detail network settings and appropriately configure the correct default address on the Pi.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply! Yes, sure. I am connecting it directly, i have not monitor.

Comment: Is it be right to sharing wifi of laptop (which connected with router) and connnect the pi, by using display for raspberry pi? Is raspberry connected with display find ip address by using sharing wifi?

Comment: @Dias-77 I haven't got the faintest idea what you are asking. Modifications to your Question should be edited into the question not Comments.